# Creating New Directory In Android Appends "app_" To It

Tags: android, directory

When creating a new directory in Android using: *context.getDir(newDir, MODE)* the program will append the string **app_** to the beginning of the string that I pass in. So instead of the string **newDir** it makes a directory called **app_newDir**.

Why does it do this? Is there a way that I can avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does this because [the command](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> abstract File     getDir(String name, int mode)
>
> Retrieve, creating if
>   needed, a new directory in which the application can place its own
>   custom data files.

If you want something without that, you want to use the `context.getFilesDir()` command, and append it appropriately

Comment: I don't understand. **context.getFilesDir()** retrieves the directory for a file that was been created for writing. This does not create the directory.

Comment: Nevermind, I understand now. I read the function's description wrong. Thanks.